# center fig caption vertically inside container

Tags: html, css

I have this block of html containing images and text. I want to center the fig caption vertically and be able to have it on multiple lines. I can't figure it out. Have tried the table-technique and also inline-block.

Here is a fiddle showing the problem.

[jsfiddle.net/qb72szt2/](http://jsfiddle.net/qb72szt2/)

Edit: code.

```
<div class="set">
<figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/141x141">
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/141x141">
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/141x141">
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</figcaption>
</figure>
```

```
.set {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

figure {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}

img {
    float: right;
    max-width: 141px;
    width: 50%;
    display:block;
}

figcaption {
    color: #83786c;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Retracted my close vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's an option to let it **behave like a table**?

So set figure to *display: table;* and img and ficaption to *display: table-cell;*
Due the nature of a table, the order of appearance is important. Therefore I swapped ficaption to be before img in source code.

Check out the code below or an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qb72szt2/1/.

```css
.set {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
figure {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
img {
  max-width: 141px;
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
}
figcaption {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #83786c;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="set">
  <figure>
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</figcaption>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/141x141">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</figcaption>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/141x141">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</figcaption>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/141x141">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. move `position: relative` rule to `figure` locator
2. use absolute postitioning on `figcaption`, i.e..
3. Use a `transform : translate` so that if figcaption contains alot of text it will be displaced appropriately.

```css
figure {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
  position: relative;
}

figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    /* I added this tranform in so final positions can be tweaked */
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    color: #83786c;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Here is an update of your fiddle **containing alot of text** - http://jsfiddle.net/889qu538/

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware about the height of the figcaption then you can use the ghost-element technique to vertically center align the text.

```
.ghost-element {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Ghost element acts like a marker for other elements with unknown heights, to align vertically, in a parent container of known height.

Updated fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/qb72szt2/3/

Comment: You can read about the ghost element trick here
http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/